# create() in Django gives me ValueError "Field 'width' expected a number but got 'NA'

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to insert several rows from .csv file into SQLite in Django. I don't want to be using import_data(), because I wanted to have a more granular control for each insertion.
My model is something like this:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    size = LengthField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, decimal_places=2,validators=(MinValueValidator(0, field_type='Length'),MaxValueValidator(100, field_type='Length'))))
```

Only name has a constraint to be unique.
Now, when i am running `get_or_create`, and have a csv row that has a blank for size, i am getting an error "ValueError - Field 'size' expected a number but got 'NA'". (For the csv rows before that,  everything is inserted correctly.)

I find it strange because in the model i have `blank=True` and `null=True` for size. What could i be doing wrong and how i could fix that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you try to pass the string `'NA'` as value for the `size` field, hence that does not work. In the logic you use to create model objects, you should replace it with `None`, so something similar to:

```
name = …
color = …
size = …

#  ↓ replace 'NA' with None
if size == 'NA':
    size = None

Box.objects.get_or_create(
    name=name,
    defaults={'color': color, 'size': size}
)
```